# Suming up values in sqlite database with php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have an sqlite database as follows

```
id number 
1    24
2    34
3    65
```

I would like to sum up the total of the number column and print the output. I've tried the following but get "sqlite_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given".

```
$database = new SQLiteDatabase('test.sqlite', 0666, $error);
$query = "SELECT SUM(Number) AS sums FROM Pushups"; 
$result = $database->query($query) or die($error); 
$i = sqlite_fetch_array($result); 

echo $i['sums'];
```

Could someone please show me the correct way to do this
Thanks

Comment: What type is `$database` and what returns the `query`-method of it. If `$database` is a `PDO` object then the `query` method runs a `PDOStatement`-instance and you'd have to use the [`fetch`-method](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) like `$i = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @vstm edited my question. $database = new SQLiteDatabase('test.sqlite', 0666, $error);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "object oriented" style for creating the database connection, you have to use it consistently for all methods. That means you can't mix the object oriented interface (the `SQLite*`-classes) and the procedural interface (the functions that start with `sqlite_*`).

So if you use the `query` method of `SQLiteDatabase` it returns an `SQLiteResult` object instance (as defined in the docs for [`SQLiteDatabase::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php)). If you check out the [`sqlite_fetch_array` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-fetch-array.php) you can see that in the object oriented style, you have to use the `SQLiteResult::fetch`-method.

So your code should look like:

```
$result = $database->query($query) or die($error); 
$i = $result->fetch(); // use the `fetch`-method of the `SQLiteResult` instance

echo $i['sums'];
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes so much sense. Didn't even know there were different styles..Thanks